# How can I throw an SQL Exception Number in one class to regular exception in another? C#

Tags: c#

I want to throw an `SqlException` Number from one class into a regular `Exception` in another.

So I want something like this (pseudo code)

SQL Class

```
catch (SqlException sqlex)
{
    if (sqlex.Number == 911)
    {
        throw new Exception("There is no database to be found");
    }
    if (sqlex.Number == 1510)
    {
        throw new Exception("There isn't a database attached");
    }
    if (sqlex.Number == 5120)
    {
        throw;  //("You do not have permissions to attach this file.");
    }
    else
    {
        throw sqlex;
    }
}
```

Class B

```
if (ex == 5120)
{
    dostuff();
}
```

The 'dirty' way around it is that I could just throw a new `Exception` with the message "5120" and then read it from there but I don't think that's the best way?

Thanks,

Comment: @Phylogenesis how can I then can I look for the number? in the if statement?

Comment: What prevents you from creating a custom exception `MyCustomSqlException` with a property `Number`? Then throw this exception and add the original exception as `InnerException` by calling the base constructor with the `SqlException` as argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, code that could potentially throw an exception is wrapped with `try{} catch{}` block on a next layer and this is combined with custom Exceptions. For possible multiple exceptions you can use multiple catch blocks:

```
public class NoPermissionSqlException : Exception
{
    public NoPermissionSqlException(string message) : base(message) {}
    // ... implement other constructors
}
```

And use it :

```
public void MyMethod()  // method that could throw an exception
{
   if (sqlex.Number == 5120)
   {
       throw new NoPermissionSqlException("You do not have permissions to attach this file.");
   }
}
```

And calling code:

```
try
{
   MyMethod();   
}
catch(NoPermissionSqlException ex)
{       
   // ... handle no permission error here
   dostuff();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   // ... default handler
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Fabjan, would the `NoPermissionsSqlException` be in the `SQL class` or `Class B`

Ignore this - sorry just saw you wrote it as a seperate class.

Comment: I think It should be a *separate* class. Let's say that the project name is MyProject and there is a DLL library Core. I'd create a folder smth like MyProject.Core.Exceptions and put all my exception files such as `NoPermissionSqlException.cs` there.

Comment: OK, I'll have a play with this. I haven't started looking to creating my own exceptions with classes so this will be very helpful. 

Could you possibly show me an example of what you mean by 'implement other constructors' in the class?

Comment: Please have a look at : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229064(v=vs.100).aspx or https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/90646/Custom-exceptions-in-C-NET

Comment: Thanks @Fabjan. Will do